# Чем отличается внешний IP адрес от публичного? Где располагается NAT?

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, сеть, ip, сетевое-программирование

Сейчас пытаюсь перейти к изучению протоколов и всего прочего связанного с интернетом, так как интересно. Смотрел разные видео, читал статьи, и так и не понял чем отличается внешний IP от публичного? Смотрю в начале видео, там говорится одна тема про публичный и приватный IP, а другая про внешний и внутренний, относящиеся к механизму NAT. В статье же просто спонтанно берут и одновременно говорят про Внешний и публичный адрес, как будто бы говорится об одном и том же. Я прекрасно понимаю, что у NAT задача перенаправлять трафик из приватных сетей в публичный, но где этот NAT находится? На ПК? В роутер встроен?

Сейчас объясню по подробнее что я не понимаю.
В моем понимании, чтобы обратиться к другой машине, нужно пройти следующий путь:

ПК (приватный IP) --> Внутренний IP --> Внешний IP --> Сервер (Публичный IP)

Вопросы:

1. Не понимаю кому принадлежит Внутренний и Внешний IP адрес. (Как я понимаю, роутеру у которого оба этих адреса?)
2. На каком устройстве находится механизм NAT? И еще, его можно называть сервисом?
3. Внешний IP является динамическим? Как узнать свой внешний IP адрес в таком случае? Если я зайду на сайт 2ip.ru, то под "Имя вашего компьютера", будет находится внешний IP адрес? (Если да, то как узнать его в консоли?)
4. Чем отличается внешний IP от публичного?

Comment: Совсем кратко: внешний-внутренний — это классификация относительно вашего роутера/локальной сети. Внешний адрес роутера как правило публичный, хотя возможен и двойной NAT. Внешний адрес роутера может быть динамическим, может быть и статическим, зависит от ISP/договора. Публичный адрес - адрес, маршрутизируемый в Интернете. Не являются публичными адреса из блоков 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, 10.0.0.0/8 и 169.254.0.0/16. Литература: Олиферы, "Компьютерные сети".

Comment: NAT работает на шлюзе. А шлюз может быть чем угодно.

Comment: Есть локальная сеть (подсеть), а есть по отношению к ней глобальная сеть (иерархия этим не ограничивается). Твой IP в подсети скрыт от внешнего мира, он известен только в твоей локальной сети. Общение с внешними устрйоствами происходит через шлюз. У шлюза есть порты (целых 65536), соединенные с портами на устрйоствах в локальной сети. Вот он и перенаправляет пакеты куда нужно.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev
Очень кратко объяснили + еще и литературу дополнительную дали. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @megorit Спасибо что объяснил!